# Vue 3 TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '5') on preview or build

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have the problem that when I build or preview the project for production I have the following error in the console:

`TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '5')`

when I run it in dev mode everything works.

Does anyone have any ideas?

HTML Part:

```html
<li>
   <span>Haarstyle: </span><small>{{ character.hair[0] }}</small>
   <input type="range" min="0" max="75"  v-model="character.hair[0]" v-on:input="customize('hair', 0, character.hair[0])">
</li>
```

Script Part:

```js
export default {
        data() {
            return {
                character: {
                    /* Identität */
                    firstname: '', /* Vorname */
                    lastname: '', /* Nachname */
                    birth: '', /* Geburtsdatum */
                    size: '', /* Körpergrösse */
                    origin: '', /* Herkunft */
                    gender: false, /* Geschlecht */
                    /* Style */
                    hair: [0, 0, 0],
                    beard: [0, 0],
                    blendData: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    faceFeatures: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    torso: 0,
                    clothing: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    clothingColor: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    headOverlays: [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
                    headOverlaysColors: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    eyeColor: 0,
                    eyebrowColor: 0,
                },
        methods: {
            changeGender: function(state) {
                if (state) {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
                    alt.emit('Client:ChangeGender', true);
                }
                else if (!state) {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
                    alt.emit('Client:ChangeGender', false);
                }
            },

            customize: function(flag, id, val) {
                console.log("Flag: " + flag + " ID: " + id + " Value: " + val);
                this.character[flag][id] = val;

                console.log(this.character)
        
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
                alt.emit('characterCustomize', flag, JSON.stringify(this.character[flag]));
            },

            customizeColor: function(flag, id, val) {
                console.log(id);

                switch (flag) {
                    case 'hair': {
                        character[flag][id] = val;
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
                        alt.emit('characterCustomize', 'haircolor', JSON.stringify(this.character[flag]));
                    }
                    case 'eyeColor': {
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
                        character[flag] = val;
                        alt.emit('characterCustomize', 'eyeColor', JSON.stringify(this.character[flag]));
                    }
                }
            },
         }
       }
```

I googled around and found these instructions but this does not work
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-cannot-set-property-of-undefined

[Errormessage:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eALsD.png)

Comment: Hard to say without any more information like the stacktrace to see what line of code the error comes from or what kind of input data the functions are receiving when the error occurs.  An example of how this error _could_ occur is if say the value of `character[flag]` is undefined, then you try setting `character[flag][id]` where id is 5, you would get this error.  Without more information it's a complete guess as to how or where this would happen.

Comment: I'll also point out that the `customize` function is doing a non-sensical assignment of `this.character[flag][id] = val;`  where if you substitue the values of the parameters being sent from the `v-on:input` it's doing the exact same as `this.character[hair][0] = this.character.hair[0]` (no difference).  Regardless of doing `x = x`, I question why even have an assignment when the [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) is already binding the value of the input to `character.hair[0]`.  Besides the emit I'm not sure the function is actually doing anything.

Comment: Hello, here is the stacktrace of the error when I run the project with `npm run preview`. I have now also removed `this.character[flag][id] = val;` as it really makes no sense. Looks to me like it's making the error in the v-model.